# Swapping values in a OneToOneField: IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following object:

```
from django.db import models

class Page(models.Model):
    prev_sibling = models.OneToOneField('self', related_name='next_sibling',
                                        null=True, blank=True)
```

I have several instances of these objects. Let's say, `A, B, C` and `D`. I have assigned the sibling relationships such that `A` has `B` as a `prev_sibling`, and `C` has `D` as `prev_sibling`.

Now imagine I want to swap `B` and `D` around. I simply re-assign the attributes, as follows:

```
A.prev_sibling = D
A.save()
C.prev_sibling = B
C.save()
```

However, this fails with an `IntegrityError`, as I no longer satisfy the uniqueness constraint that is implied by a `OneToOneField` after the first `save()`.

I tried wrapping the code in a transaction, hoping that that would make sure the save would occur atomically, and thus prevent the temporary constraint breach, like so:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    A.prev_sibling = D
    A.save()
    C.prev_sibling = B
    C.save()
```

But that did not work. What is the right way to resolve this?

**EDIT:** For the record: I also tried sequentially assigning and then saving (as follows), but as one might expect, the behaviour is no different.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    A.prev_sibling = D
    C.prev_sibling = B
    A.save()
    C.save()
```

Comment: Have you tried with [commit param in `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) ?

Comment: I do not quite see how that is relevant here. The `save` method that comes with forms seem to have this parameter, rather than `save()` on models, and it does not seem to address this issue.

Comment: Sorry, transactions has a [commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit) function.

Comment: Right - I tried that one, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're violating the database constraints. You need to clear the other one before you save it so that the database is always in a 'valid' state. Granted, after you set them to None, it's not technically a desired state, but it's a valid one for the database constraints.

This should work for you, but you obviously risk losing the relationship if something bad were to happen between saving them as `None` and setting the properties.

```
Page.objects.filter(id__in=[A.id, C.id]).update(prev_sibling=None)
A.prev_sibling = D
A.save()
C.prev_sibling = B
C.save()
```

Comment: Hmm.. I was afraid that this would be the only way, and I hoped to avoid it. I guess I'll have to accept it, for lack of anything better.

Comment: You might be able to do it all in one go using ```raw```.

Comment: Hm.. that would mean dynamically constructing a query, given that the situation I'm sketching above is a bit simplified, and the number of objects is not fixed. That's something I'd like to leave to the ORM. I'll go with setting to None and then saving.